# Mount a subdirectory on a device directly to an existing empty directory?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to just mount a subdirectory on a device (the device has valid file system like ext4) to an existing empty directory? Much like below syntax which doesn't work.

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb/usr/local/ /tmp/mounted_usr_local/
```

Thinking on this as I encountered below mount line in WSL. But if I mount /dev/sdd to another empty directory, like /tmp/tmp1, tmp1 is not he same as /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache, actually tmp1 has subdirectory isocache which is identical as the latter.

```
mount | grep sdd
/dev/sdd on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just mount a subdirectory on a file system without mounting the entire file system.  However, if you mount your entire file system in one directory, you can use a bind mount to mount just the subdirectory in another location.

For example:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/abc
$ sudo mount --bind /mnt/abc/usr/local /tmp/mounted_usr_local
```